# Comparing a Vector with three variables to a Vector with two variables

Tags: c++

I am trying to modify some code I wrote and I am having a little trouble. Essentially I have one text file that has three columns and one text file that has two columns. The text files are converted into vectors with the first two columns being a pair. I want to check if the pair in the two-column text file exists in the three-column text file. If it does exist, I want to add the full three-column version to a new vector. I am getting a number of errors and I think it has to do with trying to compare the two vectors as I do not know how to ignore the third variable when searching. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
void duplicate() {
  std::ifstream in("Measured-Isotopes_C.txt");
  if (!in.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "File is not exist" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;
  int A, Z;
  while(in >> A && in >> Z){
    vec.push_back((std::make_pair(A, Z)));
  }
  std::ifstream known("Iso-Dat.txt");
  if(!known.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "File is not exist" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>,int> vec2;
  int A1, Z1, HL;
  while(known >> A1 && known >> Z1 && known >> HL){
    vec2.push_back((std::make_pair(A1, Z1)),HL);
  }
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>,int> vec3;
  for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++){
    if(std::find(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec[i]) == vec2.end()){
      vec3.push_back(vec2[i]);
      cout<<"\t found one: "<<vec[i].first<<" "<<vec[i].second<<endl;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this function does too many things. Split it into three functions: one to read the measured isotopes, one to measure the iso data, and one to compare the results.

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>,int>` is not what you think it is. Do you want `std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>`?

Comment: a purist will have to fill in the correct terminology, but you can't declare `vector`s like this with multiple types. That is, a `vector` can only have one template argument. You can have a `vector` of `std::pair`s, but you can't define a `vector` as `std::vector<T1, T2>` as you're trying to do, only one type allowed. Not exactly sure what you're doing here, but maybe `vector`s of [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) are what you want.

Comment: That makes sense with the Tuple. But how do I use the std::find only looking at the first two ints in the tuple and comparing it to the vector of two ints?

Comment: @yano Please note that, technically, [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has *two* template parameters, the second beeing an [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). Besides that, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

A vector can only have one element, so `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>,int>` is trying to pass `int` as a custom allocator to the vector, which is not valid.

Instead you can go with for example a `std::tuple<int, int, int>` or a custom struct.

Here is a modified example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::istringstream in("1 2 "
  "3 4 "
  "5 6");
  
  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> vec;

  int A, Z;
  while(in >> A && in >> Z){
    vec.push_back((std::make_tuple(A, Z)));
  }

  std::istringstream known("1 2 3 "
  "4 5 6 "
  "7 8 9");

  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int,int>> vec2;
  int A1, Z1, HL;
  while(known >> A1 && known >> Z1 && known >> HL){
    vec2.push_back((std::make_tuple(A1, Z1, HL)));
  }

  std::vector<std::tuple<int, int,int>> vec3;

  for(const auto& pair : vec) {
    // copy_if is well suited for this purpose
    std::copy_if(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), std::back_inserter(vec3), [&](const auto& tup) {
        return std::get<0>(pair) == std::get<0>(tup) && std::get<1>(pair) == std::get<1>(tup);
    });
  }

  // structured binding is a neat feature to unpack a tuple directly
  for (const auto& [a, b, c] : vec3) {
      std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << '\n';
  }
}
```